# How to calculate percentage in groupby in Python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I got a dataframe looking like this :

```
DATE                  SCHEDULED      ARTICLE_CODE      
2021-10-01            2              001
2021-10-01            2              002
2021-10-01            2              003
2021-11-01            2              001
2021-11-01            2              002
2021-11-01            2              003
2021-11-01            2              004
...
```

What I would like is to get the percentage of the scheduled of earch article code for each date

What I'd like to get is :

```
DATE                  SCHEDULED      ARTICLE_CODE  PERCENTAGE    
2021-10-01            2              001           33.3
2021-10-01            2              002           33.3
2021-10-01            2              003           33.3
2021-11-01            2              001           25
2021-11-01            2              002           25
2021-11-01            2              003           25
2021-11-01            2              004           25
...
```

I think it is doable with groupby but I can't manage to do it

Comment: Can there be multiple `SCHEDULED` in a single date?

Comment: @Mortz Only one SCHEDULED for each ARTICLE_CODE per date

Comment: hmm, I try `df['PERCENTAGE'] = df.groupby('DATE')['ARTICLE_CODE'].apply(lambda x: x*100/x.sum())` and failed, are you sure working for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['PERCENTAGE'] = df.groupby('DATE')['ARTICLE_CODE'].apply(lambda x: x*100/(x*len(x)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for count column, divide by `100` from right side by [`Series.rdiv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rdiv.html):

```
df['PERCENTAGE'] = df['DATE'].map(df['DATE'].value_counts()).rdiv(100).round(1)
print (df)
         DATE  SCHEDULED  ARTICLE_CODE  PERCENTAGE
0  2021-10-01          2             1        33.3
1  2021-10-01          2             2        33.3
2  2021-10-01          2             3        33.3
3  2021-11-01          2             1        25.0
4  2021-11-01          2             2        25.0
5  2021-11-01          2             3        25.0
6  2021-11-01          2             4        25.0
```

Another idea:

```
df['PERCENTAGE'] = (100  / df.groupby('DATE')['ARTICLE_CODE'].transform('size')).round(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way with `pd.crosstab` -

```py
df['PERCENTAGE'] = pd.crosstab(df['DATE'], df['ARTICLE_CODE'], normalize='index').stack().where(lambda x: x>0).dropna().round(2).reset_index()[0]
```

**Output**

```
         DATE  SCHEDULED  ARTICLE_CODE  PERCENTAGE
0  2021-10-01          2             1        0.33
1  2021-10-01          2             2        0.33
2  2021-10-01          2             3        0.33
3  2021-11-01          2             1        0.25
4  2021-11-01          2             2        0.25
5  2021-11-01          2             3        0.25
6  2021-11-01          2             4        0.25
```